# Method being called twice?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a simple program that takes an inputed salary from a user and then outputs that salary + 200.
When i put in the value it displays the quesion to input the salary again, and then after putting the number in again it seems to work. 
Any idea why?

```
package learning;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SalaryReadIn {

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public SalaryReadIn () {

}

public int getSalary () {

    int currentSalary;
    System.out.println("Enter your current salary: ");
    currentSalary = scan.nextInt();
    return currentSalary;

}

public void calculate () {

    int currentSalary = getSalary();
    int newSalary = currentSalary + 200;
    System.out.println("Your new salary is: £" + newSalary);

}

public static void main (String args[]) {

    SalaryReadIn salary = new SalaryReadIn();
    salary.getSalary();
    salary.calculate();

}


}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In your main method you call `getSalary()` and `calculate()`. And in your `calculate()` method you call `getSalary()` again. So `getSalary()` will be executed twice. Once directly from `main` and once from within `calculate()`.

Comment: Thakn you very much! I just spotted it myself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As oliver has mentioned you are calling the `getSalary()` method twice.

- JVM runs the `main(String args[])` method at first.
- Then it finds the line,

  ```
  salary.getSalary();
  ```
- Then the JVM goes into `getSalary()` method and do whatever in there.
- Next as it finds the `salary.calculate()` line, it goes into that method.
- In your `calculate()` method, the line,

  ```
  int currentSalary = getSalary();
  ```

  contains the `getSalary()` method calling once again.

---

remove the following code line in the main method.

```
salary.getSalary();
```

Answer (score 1):

getSalary() was being executed twice as it is being called in the main method, and then being called in the second method that is being called.